# Laravel installation in sub-folder and horizon not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-horizon

I have installed the Laravel in sub-folder and is trying to install the horizon. After routing to "test.com/sub-folder/horizon", all the design in broken and also the internal links are pointing to main domain instead of main-domain-without-subfolder.

After the search, it seems to be the known issue which is already reported in [github issue](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/issues/660)

Has there is any work around to make horizon work when Laravel is installed in sub-folder?

Answer (score 5):

I have a solution that only involves PHP.

The issue, as pointed out by @Isaiahiroko, is the `basePath` defined for Horizon's interface. That code is in `Laravel\Horizon\Http\Controllers\HomeController::index()`. The idea is this: we are going to pass to Laravel's service container our own implementation of that controller that will override the `basePath` definition passed to Horizon's interface.

Create a new controller with code like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\View\View;
use Laravel\Horizon\Horizon;
use Laravel\Horizon\Http\Controllers\HomeController;

class HorizonHomeController extends HomeController
{
    /**
     * Overrides default horizon route to support subdirectory hosting.
     */
    public function index ()
    {
        // We use a plain request to check for the base url.
        $request = request();

        // Set up our base path. 
        $base_path = Str::substr($request->getBasePath(), 1);
        if (!empty($base_path)) {
            $base_path .= '/';
        }

        // Patch default horizon variables with our own base path.
        $variables = Horizon::scriptVariables();
        $variables['path'] = $base_path . config('horizon.path');

        // Render horizon's home view.
        return view('horizon::layout', [
            'assetsAreCurrent'       => Horizon::assetsAreCurrent(),
            'horizonScriptVariables' => $variables,
            'cssFile'                => Horizon::$useDarkTheme ? 'app-dark.css' : 'app.css',
            'isDownForMaintenance'   => App::isDownForMaintenance(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

What's left is telling Laravel's service container that when Horizon's `HomeController` is requested, it should provide our `HorizonHomeController` class. In your `AppServiceProvider`, at the end of the `register()` method, set this up:

```php
// [...]
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  // [...]
  /**
   * Register any application services.
   *
   * @return void
   * @throws InvalidConfiguration
   */
  public function register()
  {
    // [...]
    
    // Horizon's subdirectory hack
    $this->app->bind(
      Laravel\Horizon\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 
      App\Http\Controllers\HorizonHomeController::class
    );
  }
  
  // [...]
}
```

After that, you should be able to browse to `http(s)://<your-host>/<your-sub-dir>/horizon` normally.

**Considerations:**

To me this feels cleaner that patching a compiled js, which also has the downside that needs to be re-applied every time Horizon is updated (this can be mitigated with a post-update script in `composer`, tho). Also, for additional points, this solution is only overriding the method that renders the view, but not the route, which means all of Horizon's authentication mechanisms (middlewares and gates) are working exactly as described in the documentation.

Comment: Beware of trying to inject a `Request` object directly in `HorizonHomeController::index()`. That method is overriding Horizon's `HomeController::index()` and the signature of boths methods should match.

Comment: I had to also add the following code to the /routes/web.php to get this working.  `Route::get('horizon/{view?}', [\App\Http\Controllers\HorizonHomeController::class, 'index'])->where('view', '(.*)')->name('horizon.index');`

Comment: That is strange. It shouldn't be necessary. The routes defined by Horizon in its own `routes/web.php` include the route you mention pointing to Horizon's `HomeController`, which is overrided  by the `$this->app->bind()` call in AppServiceProvider as mentioned in the solution. If that is correctly set up and still it does not work, then I guess there is something more at play. This keeps working in a few of the projects I work on, but Laravel is a bit old (~ 8). Maybe in newer versions the controller or route has changed in Horizons package.

Answer (score 2):

If you desperately need to do this, here is a hack:

1. In `public\vendor\horizon\app.js`, search for `window.Horizon.basePath`
2. replace `window.Horizon.basePath="/"+window.Horizon.path;` with `window.Horizon.basePath="/[you sub-directoy]/"+window.Horizon.path;`

It should work...until you run update one day and it mysteriously stop working.

Comment: I was able to get it done by pointing sub-folder to another HTTPs port. I will also try this solution.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Isaiahiroko, you can achieve dynamic sub-directory handling (instead of hard coding your directory) with one line of code change in your `public/vendor/horizon/app.js` file

Search for `window.Horizon.basePath="/"+window.Horizon.path` and replace it with

```
window.Horizon.basePath=document.location.pathname.replace(new RegExp(window.Horizon.path+'.*$'), '')+window.Horizon.path
```